# My 256gb "Silicon Power" USB drive is fine when copying files normaly to and from it, but when I try and boot from it it becomes impossible to use

Tags: partitioning, usb, ext4

I recently bought a Silicon Power 256gb USB drive from overseas (so the warranty isn't so good), and it's fine copying files to and from it (tested with fat32, ntfs, ext4, ext2). However, when I install ubuntu on it (or any other os, like windows), which takes ages, and I boot from it, it's so slow that it's impossible to use. It takes half an hour just to boot. What's the problem? Even though this isn't strictly ubuntu-related, I would prefer to install ubuntu on it, and I don't no where else to ask this question. So I'm asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several aspects of speed.

- Writing a single file (maybe big).
- Reading a single file (maybe big).
- Writing and reading many small files (with the same total size as one big file). The speed in this case is very important, when you run an installed system. The memory hardware and the internal programming in USB pendrives can make big differences. So it is important to select a fast USB 3 pendrive according to tests, in order to get good performance with an installed system.

It is also important to modify the system in order to reduce wear, to make a USB pendrive survive with an installed system.

See the following links (and links from them) for more details.

[Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed)

[Link to USB 3.0 Flash Drive Speed Tests](http://usb.userbenchmark.com/)

[Link to USB 2 and USB 3 speed tests for installers](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=12907085#post12907085)

[Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS#Final_system_tweaks](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS#Final_system_tweaks)

-o-

A persistent live system might be a better alternative in a slow USB pendrive.

[Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)

Answer (score 0):

Not surprising that an overseas, relatively unheard of, cheap USB performs quite badly with a full-fledged OS.

According to reviews R/W speeds are around ~40 MB/s- pretty slow, indeed.

***USBs are not meant to run complete OSes!*** Most have far lower tolerances than standard HDDs and SSDs.

However, in your case, it sounds like your USB is defective as you tested it on several OSes with the same level of success (very slow).

Comment: Sorry, comments meant for other question, android app is buggy. But I used to have a cheap 32gb drive (TDK LoR Gold 3.0) from officeworks (Wikipedia: Officeworks is a chain of Australian office supplies stores) that I had ubuntu on, and it worked fine.

Comment: @superl2 Sure- it sounds like you have a defective USB. If you've installed and booted a variety of OSes then, logically, the OS isn't the issue, but the USB is.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure secure boot is not enabled in your bios settings if it is a laptop? try installing a liveboot on it. then try installing a full os on it using vbox. try using another port

Comment: What's a liveboot? Secure boot is off (legacy BIOS computer) but even if it was on that's not the problem.

Comment: You ever hear of a livecd. it is that, but it applies to thumb drives to

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwig2semqPLQAhXJ44MKHfrNBwgQFggoMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ubuntu.com%2Fdownload%2Fdesktop%2Fcreate-a-usb-stick-on-windows&usg=AFQjCNHN5pQk1ZOO4MCbajYkU-swmyrHiA&sig2=NWb_QkOI4ykC1VknjUEjhw&bvm=bv.141320020,d.amc